# Date formatting of PHP record retrieve from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, formatting

How does one pass an argument to mysql which will return records greater than today.

```
     Find('all', array('conditions' => array(
     'userstatus = ? and userdate >= ?', '-1', 'curdate()')));
```

The problem is that the date formatting isn't working.  I tried using `now()` instead of `curdate()`. Dates are stored in MySQL in the standard format: YYYY-MM-DD HH... etc.

Answer (score 0):

`FROM_UNIXTIME()` is the function you are looking for. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

```
 Find('all', array('conditions' => array(
 'userstatus = ? and userdate >= FROM_UNIXTIME(?)', '-1', time())));
```

Comment: Thank you.  This didn't work.  Although this isn't generating an error in the code, the view didn't change.  Results still show ALL userdates, rather than userdates which are just newer than yesterday.  I should include that this is an MVC site I am working on.  Thank you again